# Can chrome devtools use local files instead of the network ones while I am developing.

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is the following possible with chrome developer tools?

While working on a remote site I would like to "map" some of its resources to my local files, so that when loading the site while devtools are open - it will use my local files instead of the network ones.

I tried mapping the file to workspace files but that doesn't work and produces a Workspace mismatch error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there exists a extension that servers your purpose for Chrome browser. AFAIK, Google has not exposed such low level APIs for developing such extensions for Google Chrome browser. You could use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to do intercept http traffic and serve your own local files using its Auto Responder feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you by any chance briefly explain the purpose of resource mappings in devtools? I read through the docs but I still don't understand what's the purpose beyond saving css changes to local files.

Answer (score 0):

You also can find here some answers about how to modify HTTP response [chrome extension - modifying HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/chrome-extension-modifying-http-response)

Answer (score 0):

There is now a chrome extension that will do this [AutoResponder Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autoresponder-chrome/gdeemmakbfhjckeonddaabfpnllgahng?hl=en)