# Google Chrome Extenshion - override content of non existing site

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basicly what I want is to create extension that will override content of a certain URL:

http://overrideme

As you can imagine this page dose not exist in this world. So the effect i want to create is this. If user have my extenshion installed then if he went to http://overrideme he will see content of a page that i will provide

PS: i tryed to use "content" scripts, but they are no good, since they work with web pages that do exist.

Comment: I think the closest thing would be using [webRequest API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to substitute the url, but I don't know if it can reroute to chrome-extension:// protocol. And anyway the address displayed in the omnibox will be of the actual page, not the dummy http url.

Comment: webRequest API also won't do since it' can't replace body of a page :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/chrome-extension-modifying-http-response

Comment: The idea of webRequest is to replace the URL not the page body, so that the browser is redirected to your extension's page.

Answer (score 0):

While [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) cannot allow you to show a page with `http://overrideme` in the address bar, it can allow you to show any other page instead whenever `http://overrideme` is requested (including resources, not just page navigation)

I.e. it can redirect `http://overrideme` to `chrome-extension://yourextensionid/override.html`

You need to respond to an `onBeforeSendHeaders` event with `{redirectUrl: url}` blocking response.