# Difference between normal (popup) Chrome extension and an extension that adds a tab in developer tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

As the long title suggests, I would like to know what are the differences between a normal extension (popup) and one that adds a new tab in developer tools. A good example for the latter would be [Observe Point](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/observepoint-tag-debugger/daejfbkjipkgidckemjjafiomfeabemo).

I am new to Chrome Extensions. I tried to do a research about it, but I failed to find the answer. There seems to be little information about extensions that are hidden, like Observe Point.

I need to know if is possible to intercept a response from a server using normal extension. But it would also be nice to know the differences between them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: When you are saying the differences between normal extension(popup) and Observe Point, what exactly do you mean? And as for normal extension(popup), do you mean an extension with a [popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups)?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools this should help.

Comment: @HaibaraAi For normal, I mean the one with a popup.html, that displays an icon next to the address bar and you can click on it ( and then a popup appears).

Comment: @Learner, thank you for the resource.

Comment: @AlexD You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Normal" extensions with `popup.html` are using [popups](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#popups), and the popups can be specified through [browser action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction) or [page action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction).

Extensions like Observe Point are [DevTools extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools), they are extending devtools and add functionality to the chrome devtools.

As for "intercept a response", it has no direct relationship with what type of extension it is, as long as you declare `webRequest` along with host permissions in your `manifest.json`, you could observer, analyze, intercept, block or modify network requests in-flight as you wish.

More details you could take a look at [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest), there are very detailed examples.

**Updated:** for modifying Http responses, see this thread [chrome extension - modifying HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/chrome-extension-modifying-http-response) for more details.

Comment: Thank you! So you're basically saying that I can achieve my goal with both of them right? I'm going to do some research on DevTools extensions.

Comment: I developed an extension to download file from a page and send it to a server. i used popop to access download acrtions. and i had to send messages between popup script and content script to manage. does using developer tools make it any easier and cleaner? @haibara-ai

Answer (score 0):

The linked extension appears to utilize [`chrome.devtools.panels`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was interested more in the functional differences. What can one do that the other one can't?

Comment: @AlexD There are several examples of `DevTools` extensions at [devtools-extensions](https://github.com/thingsinjars/devtools-extension/). Functional differences in which areas? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have to develop an extension similar to Observe Point that intercepts some web analytics calls, then sends some info to a server and also intercepts the responses from the webserver. A work collegue told me that regular extensions (the ones with a popup) cannot intercept the response from a server, so I decided to do a little research to see if that's true.

Comment: @AlexD, for http reponse, I believe you could only modify response header, not the response body. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/chrome-extension-modifying-http-response

Comment: @AlexD _"and also intercepts the responses from the webserver."_ Yes, it should be possible to modify response body. See also [`ServiceWorkers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)