# Any way replace document js function when the document load completed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The loaded page html include a js function:

```
<html>
....
<body>
  <script>
  function test(){
    alert("I'm master");
   //here is the page original funciton
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And i want to write a chrome extension load my customize js file replace the current page js function `test()` ,for example :

```
new function name =>  
function test() {
    alert("I'm a new function come my chrome extension ");
}
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

Inline scripts are executed by Chrome immediately, you won't be able to prevent them from running. And we can't modify html before it's parsed: [chrome extension - modifying HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18316107).

**Your only chance** is that the function is only declared, but not being called immediately by the page script. In this case a working solution exists.

Declare a content script that will inject `<script>` element with the new function declaration:

- manifest.json

  ```js
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches": ["http://somedomain.com/blabla*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  ```
- content.js

  ```js
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).text =
      getFunctionCode(function() {
          function test() {
              alert("I'm a new function from my chrome extension");
          }
      });

  function getFunctionCode(fn) {
      return fn.toString().match(/\{([\s\S]*?)\}$/)[1];
  }
  ```

See also: [a great answer about injecting page-level scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).