# Can I create a html page in Chrome extension before it's loaded?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I need to intercept the very first request to specific server, let it be http://google.com and instead of render it inside root of the current tab create a page with two `iframes`, in the first `iframe` will be rendered site originally requested, http://google.com, in second one will be rendered lets say `http://bing.com`.

I need something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.google.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Actually I know how to intercept the very first request:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        console.log(details.requestBody);
    },
    {urls: ["*://google/*"]},
    ['requestBody']
);
```

but what to do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extension [can't directly modify http response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/chrome-extension-modifying-http-response), you may want to use some workarounds, for example, redirect this request to a predefined html template.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details)
    {
        return { redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('template.html')};
    },
    {urls: ["*://www.baidu.com/*"]},
    ['blocking']
);
```

Comment: Should this page be hosted elsewhere or it can be bundled within extension?

Comment: @Anatoly, depends on your needs, my example is assuming the template is bundled with the extension.