# Why the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest in background.js didn't wrok?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to override the source of the page by using webRequest.onBeforeRequest, but it seems not to work.
Here is the code in background/index.ts, When I add a breakpoint at line 3, and refresh the page, the breakpoint is not triggered.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  const a = details;
  const b = a;
  return undefined;
},{
  urls: ["<all_urls>"]
},["blocking"]);
```

And here is my Manifest, so why the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest in background.js didn't wrok?

````
  name: 'devtools',
  description: '',
  version: '0.0.0.1',
  manifest_version: 3,
  icons: {
    '16': 'img/icon_16.png',
    '32': 'img/icon_32.png',
    '48': 'img/icon_48.png',
    '128': 'img/icon_128.png',
  },
  action: {
    default_popup: 'popup.html',
    default_icon: 'img/icon_32.png',
  },
  devtools_page: 'devtools.html',
  background: {
    service_worker: 'src/background/index.ts',
    type: 'module',
  },
  web_accessible_resources: [
    {
      resources: ['img/icon_32.png', 'img/icon_128.png'],
      matches: [],
    },
  ],
  permissions: [
    'scripting',
    'tabs',
    'activeTab',
    'storage',
    'webRequest',
    'webRequestBlocking',
    '<all_urls>',
  ],
  host_permissions: ['<all_urls>'],```


I'd like to make chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest work in background/index.ts, so I can override the source of the page
````

Comment: ManifestV3 disallows the blocking mode of webRequest by design. Note that it can't change the body of response anyway. You'll need to use chrome.debugger for that.

Comment: It seems that  If you want to modify a request, this solution is good. If you want to modify a response based on the server-returned response, there is no way. there is no response at that point.

Comment: Like I said, you can do it via chrome.debugger, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45220932).