# How to make a chrome extension that intercepts requests and modifies the response body?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that will listen to requests and modify the response payload

I can listen to requests like this:

```
    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
      function (details) {
        console.log('onBeforeRequest', details.url)
      },
      {
        urls: ['<all_urls>']
      }
    )
```

But I can't figure out a way to modify the response. `chrome.declarativeNetRequest` can only modify headers

I saw this [Modify HTTP responses from a Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310484/modify-http-responses-from-a-chrome-extension) but none of it worked for me

I tried adding this to background:

```
chrome.debugger.getTargets((targets) => {
  targets.map((target) => {
    if (target.url.startsWith('http')) {
      console.log('tttttttttttttttt', target.url) // <---------- prints
      const debuggee = { targetId: target.id }

      chrome.debugger.attach(debuggee, '1.2', () => {
        chrome.debugger.sendCommand(
          debuggee,
          'Network.setRequestInterceptionEnabled',
          { enabled: true }
        )
      })
    }
    chrome.debugger.onEvent.addListener((source, method, _params) => {
      console.log('fuccccccccccccccccc', source, method)
      if (
        source.targetId === target.id &&
        method === 'Network.requestIntercepted'
      ) {
        console.log('yooooooooooooooo') // <--------------------- never prints
        // TODO
      }
    })
  })
})
```

But the listener callback is never fired. Also I don't see an argument for request / response data nor a way to return a modified response body

Comment: IIRC you need to send `Network.enable` first.